# HTML font not clickable because of css formating

Tags: html, css

The following HMTL and CSS code generate a datepicker. The `fa-angle-left` and `fa-angle-right` are clickable elements. Hover, the `fa-angle-left` element can't be click because the padding of the `datepicker-date` is above the `fa-angle-left`. I found several topics on this but I can't seem to make a solution work:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="datepiker-container">
  <span class="fa fa-angle-left fa-3x datepicker" {{action "dateBack"}}></span>
  <div class="datepicker-date">
    <h4 class="datepicker">{{dayOfWeek}}</h4>
    <h2 class="datepicker">{{monthDay}}</h2>
    <h5 class="datepicker">{{month}}  <span style:"font-weight:800">{{year}}</span></h5>
  </div>
  <span class="fa fa-angle-right fa-3x datepicker" {{action "dateForward"}}></span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.datepiker-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 145px !important;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px !important;
}

div.datepicker-date {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 87px !important;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px !important;
}


h2.datepicker {
  margin: -5px 0px -5px 0px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  font-size: 250%;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 45px;
}


h4.datepicker {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 9px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  width: 45px;
}


h5.datepicker {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  width: 45px;
}


span.datepicker {
  padding: 8px 0px 7px !important;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  position:absolute;
}

span.datepicker:hover {
  padding: 8px 0px 7px !important;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  position:absolute;
}
```

**Questions:** What is the proper approach to make the `fa-angle-left` clickable?

Thanks

Comment: Please create a minimal working fiddle that other people can recreate your problem. (1) Not everybody knows you are using FontAwesome; (2) replace your template expression with meaningful content; (3) your HTML is invalid: `<span style:"font-weight:800">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix would be bring the icon to top:

```
span.datepicker {
  padding: 8px 0px 7px !important;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1000; /* add this rule */
}
```

Another approach is use `margin` over `padding` on the center part:

```
div.datepicker-date {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 87px !important;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px !important; /* use margin over padding */
}
```

And by the way, your HTML is invalid:

```
<span style:"font-weight:800">
           ^
            this should be an equal sign (=)
```